# com.chaquo.python.PyException: ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version

Tags: python, android, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chaquopy

I am currently using Chaquopy to implement Python code into Android Studio. However, I am having trouble initializing selenium's chromedriver in Python. Whenever I try initializing by using the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver.exe, options=opt)`, I either get the error "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions" or "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH". So instead, I imported ChromeDriverManager and called `driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=opt)`. Running my program gives the following error:

```
    Process: com.example.test3, PID: 20964
    com.chaquo.python.PyException: ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version
        at <python>.webdriver_manager.utils.chrome_version(utils.py:112)
        at <python>.webdriver_manager.driver.get_latest_release_version(driver.py:58)
        at <python>.webdriver_manager.manager.__get_latest_driver_version(manager.py:21)
        at <python>.webdriver_manager.manager.__get_version_to_download(manager.py:27)
        at <python>.webdriver_manager.manager.download_driver(manager.py:36)
        at <python>.webdriver_manager.chrome.install(chrome.py:28)
        at <python>.login.web_scrape(login.py:57)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:281)
        at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrows(chaquopy_java.pyx:253)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(Native Method)
        at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:209)
        at com.example.test3.LoginWaterloo$1.onClick(LoginWaterloo.java:37)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Any advice on how to overcome this error? I have seen a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175675/making-program-using-chromedriver-getting-error-could-not-get-version-for-chr) that shares the same problem but could not understand the answer.

Comment: The problem has definitly to do with what you provide in the variable 'opt'. Can you give where you give a value of opt and tell us what you wanted to do with this

Comment: If chromedriver.exe is a Windows executable, you won't be able to run it on Android. As I understand the ChromeDriver documentation, they support using it on your Windows/Max/Linux development machine to control an Android device, but not running it on Android directly.

Comment: @dylanvanw Here is my code for initializing opt: `opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` and `opt.add_argument("--headless")`. I added the argument "--headless" since I expected the chromedriver to open a browser which I wanted to hide from the user.

Comment: @mhsmith Is there any way for me to run chromedriver through Android's browser(i.e. Webview)?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used any webdriver tool, so I don't know anything more.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked with providing the options not to the options parameter but the chrome_options parameter.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options,  service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=logs/chromedriver.log'])
```

Comment: If it is the correct answer please checkmark it as being the correct answer. If not just let me know and I can change my answer to help you.

Comment: I replaced my code with the following and got the same error as above