# Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

Web **scraping** with selenium works fine on my mac local machine but when I push to live Ubuntu server, I get the following error

```
Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version
```

when I try to run

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
```

> The code is deployed on AWS ec2 instance

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/73

Comment: Hi, I am supporting webdriver_manager on python. Q: Is google chrome installed on ubuntu or chromium browser?

Comment: @gore installing chromium-chromedriver on ubuntu server worked for me, thank you for your help

Comment: @Zohaib. I am glad to hear your problem has been solved.

But to be truth: installing chromium-chromedriver from ubuntu's repository is not the solution for webdriver-manager's issue have been described in the topic. 

You solved it by installing chromium-chromedriver. Then i suggest that you have Chromium browser, not the GoogleChrome. I have added the answer for the question from topic. For the people who will come here with same problem with webdriver-manager.

Comment: Yes, I have chromium browser my bad, I'll try your solution as well and get back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @gore in the comments installing chromium-chromedriver on ubuntu server worked for me

**On Ubuntu 20.04**

```
pip install selenium
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

Answer (score 3):

Possible: you don't have GoogleChrome or your OS doesn't know about it. I suggest that you use Chromium browser.

The solution if you want to download Chromium webdriver by webdriver-manager:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()
```

Comment: I tried this way still show this error, seems did not work.@gore

Comment: @Dolphin what version of webdriver-manager do you use?

Comment: I am using `webdriver_manager==3.5.2` right now.@gore

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Chromium, try installing Google Chrome instead of using chromium. As far as I know selenium is designed for Chrome. There is another related topic here: [Making program using Chromedriver, getting error: "Could not get version for Chrome with this command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175675/making-program-using-chromedriver-getting-error-could-not-get-version-for-chr)

Answer (score -3):

try it like this

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

here's another hint for you http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities