# Selenium chromdriver keeps on giving me error

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have been able to make use of selenium chrome for a sometime. I have tried to catch an error using

```
try:
    #check if it already exist before doing anything
    webdriver.driver
except:
    chromeBrowser=ChromeDriverManager().install() 
    ....... some other code here
```

The above code works very well, it catches the error and loads the browser without any problem. Suddenly it started giving me this error and it does not go beyond that. It does not even go into the internet at all.

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\python_src\school\school\host\views.py", line 2333, in loopTest
    chromeBrowser = ChromeDriverManager().install()
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 23,
in __init__
    self.driver = ChromeDriver(name=name,
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 54,
in __init__
    self.browser_version = chrome_version(chrome_type)
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\utils.py", line 155,
in chrome_version
    raise ValueError(f'Could not get version for Chrome with this command: {cmd}')
ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBe
acon" /v version
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 925, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 672, in format
    record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 622, in formatException
    traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], tb, None, sio)
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 103, in print_exception
    for line in TracebackException(
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\trio\_core\_multierror.py", line 393, i
n traceback_exception_init
    traceback_exception_original_init(
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 508, in __init__
    self.stack = StackSummary.extract(
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 366, in extract
    f.line
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 288, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 1288: invalid start byte
Call stack:
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, i
n wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 106, in inner_run
    self.server_cls(
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py", line 143, in run
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=self.signal_handlers)
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", li
ne 255, in run
    self._asyncioEventloop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\pure_spring\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", li
ne 271, in _onTimer
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 991, in
 runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "C:\python_src\venv\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py", line 290, in applica
tion_checker
    logger.error(
Message: 'Exception inside application: %s'
Arguments: (NameError("name 'webdriver' is not defined"),)
```

Please what am i to do now, I do not know what to do. I have even removed the try exception statement completely, but that has not helped.

**Update**

All this started shortly after I upgraded selenium. After that i tried to reverse the upgrade but could get get the initial version But i still used another one, yet it still gives me the same error.

Normally before the selenium upgrade it downloads the driver for me and runs the browser. but now it does not even go to my internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is this error deep in your error stack:

```
Could not get version for Chrome with this command: reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Chrome\BLBe
acon" /v version
```

Following this error leads to a few duplicate questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081326/could-not-get-version-for-chrome-with-this-command-google-chrome-version-g) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175675/making-program-using-chromedriver-getting-error-could-not-get-version-for-chr). Have you tried suggestions in these threads? Does any of them solve your issue?

It seems that python is not able to find chrome and that is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I have tried to change it from google-chrome to chromium and back. It is still the same error i am getting